# BeautifulSoup, finding the nth table without using find_all()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I want to find the nth table using BeautifulSoup. So far this has been doing the job for me.

`table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})[nth]`

But if I know for sure it is the nth table where n is defined by me, is there a way to avoid searching through and saving all previous tables? I feel like if there was a way to only get the table if it's the nth one my code would run much faster. The tables are from wikipedia.

Comment: Perhaps `find()` and then [find_next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) n-1 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `.select` with `nth-of-type`. I am not sure if this will make your code run any faster, for that please checkout the [improving performance](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#improving-performance)  section of the documentation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<table class="1">
</table>
<table class="2">
</table>
<table class="3">
</table>
<table class="4">
</table>
<table class="5">
</table>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('table:nth-of-type(3)'))
```

Output

```
[<table class="3">
</table>]
```

The css selector `.class:nth-of-type(n)` does NOT seem to work with BeautifulSoup. But if you know the parent class of the tables, you could do something like `'.parent table:nth-of-type(n)'`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div class="parent1">
<table class="tbl">
not our table 1
</table>
<table class="tbl">
not out table 2
</table>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
<table class="tbl">
our table 1
</table>
<table class="tbl">
our table 2
</table>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('.parent2 table:nth-of-type(2)'))
```

Ouput

```
[<table class="tbl">
our table 2
</table>]
```

The above output can also be accomplished by `soup.select('.parent2 .tbl ~ .tbl')`